# Verify FIT image against data corruption in linux userland

Tags: linux, boot, crc, u-boot, userland

How can i check the contents of a FIT image against data corruption in linux userland?

Use case: In an embedded application, I have a FIT image in a NAND partition and I want to know if it would be able to boot (without actually booting it).

Ideally, I'd like to do that without the need to dump that whole partition into a file (since this would eat too much ram or flash respectively).

Let's say the image is available as `/dev/flash/bootimage` (or as some mtd block). I have tried to `dd` that flash device into a `/tmp/bootimage` file and run `mkimage -l`on that which verifies the header but *not* the data.

I could use `dumpimage` to dump a specific part of the whole fit image and run crc32 on that. This would technically work but also it requires me to have the image available as a file somewhere (seems, it cannot read from `/dev/flash/bootimage` or from `stdin` directly).

My goal would actually be something like this:

```
nice -19 dd if=/dev/flash/bootimage | verifybootimage
```

... which means i could make that somewhat a background task which is scheduled once a day with very low priority and the output stream of `dd` is checksummed (`nice -19 dd if=/dev/flash/bootimage | cksum` would work like that but i cannot tell whether the cksum output is correct since the header itself counts into the cksum)

Answer (score 1):

U-Boot comes with a tool fit_check_sign. You can check the integrity of your RSA signed FIT image like this:

```
tools/fit_check_sign -f image.fit -k test.dtb
```

You have to provide the signed fit image and a binary device tree containing the public key.

The public key is added to the device tree when you create a FIT image and provide the device-tree as parameter -K of command tools/mkimage.